# A Tough Series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(2k+1)-1}{k+1}=-\gamma+\log(2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

I have done series with $\zeta(2k)$ and $\zeta(k)$, but I have no idea with this one:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(2k+1)-1}{k+1}=-\gamma+\log(2)$$

$\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

This value was given by *Mathematica*. Any hint?

Comment: Expand $\zeta(2 k + 1)$ and interchange summation order?

Comment: @vonbrand I think you get a logarithmic sum by doing that. How do you evaluate that?

Comment: The same constant arises in
$$lim_{n \to \infty} \left(log(2n+1)-H_n\right) = log(2)-\gamma$$
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/439184/134791

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I solved it myself.

First we note that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(2k+1)-1}{k+1} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)n^{2k+1}}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left( -\frac{1}{n}- n\log \left( 1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$$

Then
$$\begin{aligned} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(2k+1)-1}{k+1} &=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left( -\frac{1}{n}- n\log \left( 1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right) \\ &= \lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=2}^N \left( -\frac{1}{n}- n\log \left( 1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\\ &= \lim_{N\to \infty} \left[ -H_N+1-\sum_{n=2}^N n \log(n^2-1)+2\sum_{n=2}^Nn\log(n)\right]\\ &= \lim_{N\to \infty} \left[ -H_N+1-\sum_{n=2}^N \left(n\log(n+1) +n\log(n-1)-2n\log(n)\right)\right]
\\ &= \lim_{N\to \infty} \Bigg[ -H_N+1+\log(2)-\sum_{n=3}^{N+1}(n-1)\log(n)-\sum_{n=3}^{N-1}(n+1)\log(n) \\ &\quad+\sum_{n=3}^N2n\log(n)\Bigg] \\ &= \lim_{N\to \infty}\left[-H_N-N\log(N+1)-(N-1)\log(N)+2N\log(N)+1+\log(2) \right]\\ &= \lim_{N\to \infty}\left(- \left(H_N-\log N \right)+\log(2)+1-N\log \left( 1+\frac{1}{N}\right)\right)\\&= \lim_{N\to \infty}\left( - \left(H_N-\log N \right)+\log(2)+\mathcal{O}(N^{-1})\right)
\end{aligned}$$

Since $\displaystyle \gamma=\lim_{N\to \infty}(H_N-\log(N))$, we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(2k+1)-1}{k+1} =-\gamma+\log(2)$$

Comment: (+1) I hope you don't think my answer is too close to yours.  If you do, let me know and I will remove it.

Answer (score 4):

This is similar in some respects, but different in others, from the answer provided by Shobhit Bhatnagar.  I also thought a detailed explanation of the steps might prove useful.

First we show a binocular telescoping series:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^m\log\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)
&=\sum_{n=2}^m\log\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)+\sum_{n=2}^m\log\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)\tag{1a}\\
&=\log(m)+\log\left(\frac2{m+1}\right)\tag{1b}\\[3pt]
&=\log\left(\frac{2m}{m+1}\right)\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: $\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}=\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{n}{n+1}$
$\text{(1b)}$: evaluate $2$ telescoping sums
$\text{(1c)}$: simplify

Now we use $(1)$ to compute the sum:
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\zeta(2k+1)-1}{k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k+1}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^{2k+1}}\tag{2a}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k+1}\frac1{n^{2k+1}}\tag{2b}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(n\log\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)-\frac1n\right)\tag{2c}\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=2}^m\left((m-(m-n))\log\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)-\frac1n\right)\tag{2d}\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(m\log\left(\frac{2m}{m+1}\right)-\sum_{n=2}^m\sum_{j=n+1}^m\log\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)-(H_m-1)\right)\tag{2e}\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(m\log\left(\frac{2m}{m+1}\right)-\sum_{j=3}^m\sum_{n=2}^{j-1}\log\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)-(H_m-1)\right)\tag{2f}\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(m\log\left(\frac{2m}{m+1}\right)-\sum_{j=3}^m\log\left(\frac{2(j-1)}{j}\right)-(H_m-1)\right)\tag{2g}\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(m\log\left(\frac{2m}{m+1}\right)-(m-2)\log(2)-\log\left(\frac2m\right)-(H_m-1)\right)\tag{2h}\\[6pt]
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(m\log\left(\frac{m}{m+1}\right)+1+\log(2)+\log(m)-H_m\right)\tag{2i}\\[9pt]
&=\log(2)-\gamma\tag{2j}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: expand $\zeta(2n+1)-1=\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{k^{2n+1}}$
$\text{(2b)}$: switch order of summation
$\text{(2c)}$: $n\log\left(\frac1{1-1/n^2}\right)-\frac1n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(k+1)n^{2k+1}}$
$\text{(2d)}$: write infinite sum as a limit and $n$ as $m-(m-n)$
$\text{(2e)}$: apply $(1)$, the definition of the Harmonic Numbers, and $\sum\limits_{j=n+1}^m1=m-n$
$\text{(2f)}$: switch the order of summation
$\text{(2g)}$: apply $(1)$
$\text{(2h)}$: evaluate the telescoping sum
$\text{(2i)}$: cancel and combine terms
$\text{(2j)}$: evaluate the limits

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
{\zeta\pars{2k + 1} - 1 \over k + 1}} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{\zeta\pars{2k + 1} - 1}
\pars{2\int_{0}^{1}t^{2k + 1}\,\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] = & \
2\int_{0}^{1}t\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
\zeta\pars{2k + 1} - 1}t^{2k}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = & \
2\int_{0}^{1}t\bracks{%
{1 \over 2t} - {\pi \over 2}\cot\pars{\pi t} - {1 \over 1 - t^{2}} + 1 - \gamma - \Psi\pars{1 + t}}\,\dd t
\end{align}
where I used the [A & S ${\bf\color{black}{6.3.15}}$ Digamma Function Identity](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_259.htm) . The integration yields right away the correct result:
$$
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
{\zeta\pars{2k + 1} - 1 \over k + 1} = \ln\pars{2} - \gamma}} \approx 0.1159
$$